# Problem with $wpdb

Tags: plugins

I was trying to learn to use $wpdb but I don't know why it's not working.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  TEST

*/



if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}


function ctz_show(){            
    global $wpdb;

    $table = "${$wpdb->prefix}postmeta";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    var_dump($results);
}

add_shortcode( 'cotizador', 'ctz_show' );
```

The output is always

> array(0) { }

Even if I change the name of the table.

Comment: That could be a stupendously problematic query, are you sure you don't want to use `get_post_meta`? Doing a direct query will bypass all the caches! It can also leak personal data which would be considered a data breach in most countries ( definately in EU countries )

Comment: I try to design a search engine, and I want to use "where" and "like" to use it with ajax, so I would like to use it directly in queries.

Comment: That's going to be extremely slow, with a very heavy load on the database. The post meta table was built for fetching all key/value pairs for a given post ID, it wasn't built for searching and filtering. Thats why we have taxonomy tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work much better ;)

```
  $table = "{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta";
  $query = "SELECT * FROM {$table}";
```